# Errors when I catkin build, may someone help me?

Tags: ros, catkin, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Errors

```
<< moveit_tutorials:make /home/tommaso/ws_moveit/logs/moveit_tutorials/build.make.007.log
/home/tommaso/ws_moveit/src/moveit_tutorials/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/src/move_group_interface_tutorial.cpp:37:62: fatal error: moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
 #include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h>
                                                              ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: ** [doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/CMakeFiles/move_group_interface_tutorial.dir/src/move_group_interface_tutorial.cpp.o] Erro 1
make[1]: ** [doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/CMakeFiles/move_group_interface_tutorial.dir/all] Erro 2
make[1]: ** Esperando que outros processos terminem.
make: ** [all] Erro 2
cd /home/tommaso/ws_moveit/build/moveit_tutorials; catkin build --get-env moveit_tutorials | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/make --jobserver-fds=6,7 -j; cd -
...............................................................................
Failed     << moveit_tutorials:make                            [ Exited with code 2 ]
Failed    <<< moveit_tutorials                                 [ 0.3 seconds ] 
Abandoned <<< pr2_moveit_generated                             [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< moveit_ros_benchmarks_gui                        [ Unrelated job failed ]
Abandoned <<< moveit_setup_assistant                           [ Unrelated job failed ]
Finished  <<< moveit_ros_visualization                         [ 0.6 seconds ] 
[build] Summary: 26 of 30 packages succeeded.                                  
[build]   Ignored:   7 packages were skipped or are blacklisted.               
[build]   Warnings:  None.                                                     
[build]   Abandoned: 3 packages were abandoned.                                
[build]   Failed:    1 packages failed.                                        
[build] Runtime: 6.9 seconds total.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279471/errors-when-i-catkin-build,-may-someone-help-me?/) by [bellonetom](https://answers.ros.org/users/33239/bellonetom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-01-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-10**:
Welcome! What commands are you running and what tutorial are you following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your build is failing because the compiler cannot find the `moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h` file. This is probably caused by the include path's not being setup correctly in your CMakeLists.txt file. Can you post of the contents of this file in your question and we'll see if we can get this sorted out for you.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0